# Using Tar, how to preserve permissions of parent folders when given just a specific file?

Tags: permissions, terminal, tar

Say, I have a folder with some fancy permissions:

```
mkdir abc
mkdir abc/def
chmod 777 abc
```

Now I want to create a backup:

```
tar -cpzvf test.tar.gz abc/def/
```

Now let's remove abc/ and restore it from the archive:

```
rm -rf abc/
tar -xpzvf test.tar.gz
```

`abc/` will not have the original permissions anymore:

```
find abc -printf "%m:%f\n"
755:abc
```

I know that if I would create the tar file by providing abc/ (not abc/def/) as parameter, it would restore the permissions of both folders just fine. However, in my case I need to explicitly provide abc/def/ as parameter. Is there a way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2):

To follow-up on @schily's fine answer, to add the top-level directory `abc` to the  archive, without adding any of its subdirectories other than `def`, with GNU `tar`, you'd do:

```
tar -zcf file.tgz --no-recursion abc --recursion abc/def
```

With  libarchive's `bsdtar`, or `pax`, you can always revert to have `find` generate the exact list of files you want:

```
(printf 'abc\0'; find abc/def -print0) | bsdtar -zcnf file.tgz --null -T -
```

Answer (score 1):

Your umask is applied. Try:

umask 000; tar -xpzvf test.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

Your problems is that the directory `abc` is not in the archive and thus cannot be restored from the archive.

Since it is needed but missing, `tar` creates it with default permissions under your credentials.

If you like to restore the permissions from `abc` as well, you need to put it into the archive.